# Can a single big triangle be formed from given n smaller triangles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, triangles

I found this question quite intriguing.

The question was given 4 (or any generic n) triangles with the length of each side known. Is it possible to create a bigger triangle by putting these smaller triangles together?
ex 2 triangles with sides (3, 4, 5) and (4, 3, 5) can be put together to create a bigger triangle (5, 5, 8).

The only method I could think of was to try all possible combinations of placing the triangles together (by joining common sides) and see if the result is a valid triangle.

Comment: That's not enough. There might be a combination where _none_ of the sides is put against a side of the same length, yet the whole picture fits together nicely.

Comment: Yes I realized that can't think of any other solution than brute force for now